# Could not load cache configuration resource file://coherence-cache-config.xml

Tags: java, weblogic12c, distributed-caching, oracle-coherence

I am using Weblogic 12.1.2 which contains 1-admin & 3-manage-servers(under 1-cluster) in the same machine.I want to store some data into a cache(distributed) which must be available among all the manager-servers inside a cluster.
So I am using oracle coherence feature for the same.
whenever I started coherence.sh it always gives the error saying that
"**Could not load cache configuration resource file://coherence-cache-config.xml**".
I have done some analysis and came to know that its always taking configuration from coherance.jar which comes with WebLogic. even after changing the PRE_CLASSPATH to my custom coherance.jar. it's always pointing to the WebLogic jar.Due to this i am not able to override **"coherence-cache-config.xml" & "tangosol-coherence-override.xml"**.

Can you please suggest something. how can I override WebLogic default coherance.jar resources to my custom ones?

Comment: Require more details:1. What's the topology/caching pattern are you planning to use?
2. The 3 managed servers you've mentioned whether that's for your application or for the Coherence cache servers?
3. Starting with Weblogic 12c, it's preferable to deploy coherence inside their own managed server, (You'll create a coherence gar and deploy to the managed server) - This is considering you plan to deploy coherence as separate cache service.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Coherence documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/gs_config.htm#COHDG5009), by default Coherence will use first `coherence-cache-config.xml` file found in classpath. But in your case it tries to load it from `file://coherence-cache-config.xml` location. It means that location of this file is somewhere overriden (either in `tangosol-coherence-override.xml` file or through `tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig` system property).

What more, `file://coherence-cache-config.xml` seems to be not a valid file uri. When I try to do:

```
new File(new URI("file://coherence-cache-config.xml"))
```

it results in exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
```

So, make sure you properly set `coherence-cache-config.xml` file location in `tangosol-coherence-override.xml` file or through `tangosol.coherence.cacheconfig` system property (the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/gs_config.htm#COHDG5009) explains in details, how to do it).

Comment: could you define what do you mean by properly set the location ?